# Meanings of commonly used acronyms in software testing

Tags: terminology

Many of the questions and answers on SQA make frequent use of acronyms for things that many people would have an idea of what the spelled out term means, but might have a hard time deciphering the acronym. It would be helpful to have a list of acronyms and what they stand for, as used on this site.

I've started a CW answer so others can add to the list.

Comment: There are zillions of websites with glossary of terms all over internet. Seems like many people are trying to establish online presence and expertise, and such glossary is one of the easy and obvious starts. I do not see why we would want to compete with them.

Comment: just google "commonly used acronyms in software testing"

Comment: I've added more to the great list below.

Comment: Given that several people have found this question useful and contributed to the list in the wiki answer, I would respectfully request that it be reopened. Even if the answer isn't a complete list, it is helpful for newcomers, and since many of the terms are frequently used _on this site_, I believe many people will be looking around on this site for definitions. Also, in response to the google argument, this is already in the top 3 google results, and the first two are rather antiquated and not really focused on testing (e.g. ACM? XML?).

Comment: Best practice for the use of acronyms is they should be written out in full at first usage in a body of text and this convention should be used on Software Quality Assurance & Testing (SQA) exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **AUT** Application Under Test **or** Automated Unit Test(s)
- **BDD** Behavior-Driven Development
- **BP** Best Practice
- **CI** Continuous Integration
- **CD** Continuous Delivery
- **DRE** Defect Removal Efficiency
- **E2E** End to End testing
- **HCI** Human Computer Interaction, or Human Computer Interface
- **IV&V** Independent Verification and Validation
- **KPI** Key Performance Indicator
- **MTBF** [Mean Time Between Failures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures)
- **PRD** Project/Product Requirement Document(s)
- **QA** Quality Assurance; **or** Quality Analyst when referring to a person
- **QAR** Quality Acceptance Review
- **QС** Quality Control
- **QE** Quality Engineer
- **QO** Quality Owner
- **RT** Release Test
- **SBTM** [Session-Based Test Management](http://www.satisfice.com/sbtm/)
- **SDET** Software Development Engineer in Test
- **SDLC** Software Development Life Cycle
- **SET** Software Engineer in Test
- **SPEC** A software specification, i.e. a test
- **SRD** Services Reported Defect (also know as a Production Defect that is reported by a services team member, services in the sense of customer service/support)
- **SRP** Software Release Process
- **SUT** System/Software Under Test
- **TC** Test Case
- **TDD** Test-Driven Development/Design
- **UAT** User Acceptance Testing
- **V&V** Verification and Validation

Answer (score 1):

**There is no standard terminology in testing so if you are unclear about a word or acronym being used, it's always best to ask.**

Organizations will develop their own acronyms and values for words, so it's best to start there. When you hear a word or acronym, ask what it means. Then do some Google research to see what other people are saying or using the term for. Maybe look it up in a dictionary and form an opinion / understanding for it's value.

If it makes sense, make a list of your companies acronyms but not ones used by other people. Then use this list to research the topics and try to understand them with some depth. e.g What does it mean, what value does this provide, what are downsides, etc.??

Acronyms by themselves don't have much value or add to the conversation. If I said *I'm an SDET in an Agile SDLC using TDD / BDD practices to write TCs in an attempt to improve QC* and you were able to transfer those acronyms into the full words, would you have any better idea what I was talking about? Probably not.

Comment: Yes, when I expand abbreviations in your statement I have better idea what you were talking about. Even if your understanding of Software Engineer in Test might be different than mine, it is still less ambiguous than its short form (SDET).